# About ajax post data to PHP

Tags: php, ajax, html, geolocation

I'm newbie to Ajax, I know when I want to pass data to PHP file I need to use Ajax, but I not sure the Ajax can use like what I coded. If can't, anybody can help me on this? Cause I want to use the html5 geolocation to get the user location. I tried geoplugin before but the IP I get always is the server IP not the user IP, I got try to ask here for the geoplugin but no work. I have tried this html5 geolocation to display my lon and lat, it is correct one, but I want to pass the variable to another PHP file for calculate the nearest distance with data get from MySQL.

In index.php

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation);
} else { 
    $('#location').html('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
}
});

function showLocation(position) {
var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'index1.php',
    data:'latitude='+latitude+'&longitude='+longitude
    }
});
}
</script>
```

In index1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","id2135226_ukwai1203","ukwai1203");
mysqli_select_db($link,"id2135226_demo");
$lat=$_POST['latitude'];
$lon=$_POST['longitude'];
$sql = "select branch_id,(6371 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(($lat - 
branch_lat)*pi()/180/2),2)+COS($lat*pi()/180 
)*COS(branch_lat*pi()/180)*POWER(SIN(($lon-branch_lon)*pi()/180/2),2)))) 
as 
distance From Branch ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 1";
$res=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
$_SESSION['location']=$row['branch_id'];
?>
<script>

window.location="http://ukwai1203.000webhostapp.com/fyp/user/shop.php";
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: @JayBlanchard no error, just a blank page, i put this file on a web hosting server

Comment: @JayBlanchard forgot to add the library, but after i add, still blank page

Comment: @JayBlanchardi added <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> this to the upper of the file in index.php

Comment: Why shouldn't it be a blank page? The only HTML in it is a `<script>` element, and your JS only makes an Ajax request: It does nothing with the response and never writes anything to the page.

Comment: @Quentin so the ajax no run the index1.php?

Comment: It makes an HTTP request to the server. The server executes the PHP. The server sends the output of the PHP back to the browser. The browser stores it in a variable and gives that variable back to JavaScript. Your JavaScript then ignores it.

Comment: @Quentin so if i can't do something like this, how can i get the lon and lat from the js and used to calculate the min dist with mysql data? cause i can't get the mysql in the js

Comment: You can do something like that. You just have to finish reading whatever Ajax tutorial got you that far as **do something with the response** instead of stopping half way through.

Comment: @Quentin Okay, thanks

Answer (score -3):

change your code to this:

```
function showLocation(position) {
var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
$.ajax({
   method:"POST",
    url:"index1.php",
    data:{
   latitude : latitude,
   longitude : longitude
    }
  });//ajax end

}//function end
```

Consider using IDE like eclipse to help you spot missing brackets etc.
And when working by modifying old code check libraries versions like jquery version.

Comment: This reads like a game of spot-the-difference, not an answer. What did you change? Why should it solve the problem? (It looks like you are suggesting letting jQuery construct the POST body instead of doing it manually … which is a good best practise but won't help with the problem).

Comment: @Quentin please read carefully before down voting and posting nonsense comments. The code posted has unbalanced brackets and the solution for this in my opinion is to use an IDE rather than pointing to where it is.You can also find the spot of changes in comments in the code.

Comment: You could explain that more clearly by saying "You have an extra `}` in your code that you need to remove". (This still doesn't solve the problem though as the HTTP response is still ignored).

Comment: note that the extra right bracket in the code implies the code previous state where data wasn't constructured manually.

Comment: But the OP is not interested in the response (he should probably )  because he is using the coordinates to get a branch and store it in the session